# Angular Checking What Filters Return

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list with ng-repeat and a filter , the filter filters based on an html input . If the filter produces an empty list , I want to show the user some informative message . I can't figure out how...

```
 Search the list: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
 <div ng-controller="my-ctrl">
    <ul id="list">
        <li ng-repeat="element in myElements | filter:searchText" >
           {{element.data }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    ***<div>{{myElements.length}}</div>*** //length stays
      // the same no matter what the filter is returning...
       <div ng-show="myElements.length">My Informative Msg</div>
```

What I tried doing was showing my informative msg based on myElements.length , I thought that the filter will update the value of myElements in my scope . However , what I find as I search for items (e.g reducing or enlarging the list) is that myElements.length stays the same .

Is there some elegant solution to know when the filter is empty , or more generally to know what the filter is returning ?

Comment: can you add your model in question. myElements.length works as array.length in javascript. It can also work as boolean. !myElements.length is true when array is empty. otherwise is false. I guess the problem is in your model (it does not update myElements reference)

maybe this can help you: http://jsfiddle.net/C29As/

Comment: There is no filter in your example ... can't see how its the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a neat trick for that. Instead of filtering the real list, create a new filtered list "in the fly" which will contain only the filtered items or none. If none, show the message.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"];
});
```

And:

```
<input ng-model="searchText" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter: searchText)">
    {{ item }}
  </li>
</ul>
<div ng-hide="filteredItems.length">There is no item matching</div>
```

So if your filter doesn't match any item, you will see the message.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3os7gIxSjlyDO1CGKcFT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create your own filter which will do that.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/QXSR8/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    {{answer | empty}}
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('project', []).
  filter('empty', function() {
    return function(input) {

        if (!input || !input.length){
           return "Array is empty"; 
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
});
```